# How to generate a customised histogram with pgf plots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, histogram

I am trying to generate a histogram like the following:

[image]

While going through the examples [pgf plots](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Pgfplots_package), I was able to generate a histogram similar to the following:

[image]

using the code from the example link shared above:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{csvsimple}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}



    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        x tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
        ylabel=Year,
        enlargelimits=0.05,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        ybar interval=0.7,
    ]
    \addplot 
        coordinates {(2012,408184) (2011,408348)
            (2010,414870) (2009,412156)};
    \addplot 
        coordinates {(2012,388950) (2011,393007) 
            (2010,398449) (2009,395972)};
    \legend{Men,Women}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Is there a way with `pgf plots`, where I could generate custom looking histogram?

Comment: How about `rounded corners`: `\addplot[rounded corners=8pt,fill=blue!60!black] 
        coordinates {(2012,408184) (2011,408348)
            (2010,414870) (2009,412156)};
    \addplot[rounded corners=3pt,fill=red!60!black]  
        coordinates {(2012,388950) (2011,393007) 
            (2010,398449) (2009,395972)};`?

Comment: @marmot, good idea, however the legend is than screwy ...  can you fix this?

Comment: @marmot Could we also remove the `y` axis and have the corresponding values at the top of histogram?

Comment: @Zarko Yes. It took me a while to realize that the OP uses `ybar interval` rather than `ybar`, where I was stuck... ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a simple-minded proposal. Note that I changed from `ybar interval` to `ybar`, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99389/121799). The main idea is to use `rounded corners` but then one has to fix the legend to have a smaller radius of the rounded corners. I also removed the y axis and added `nodes near coords`, as requested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={
        \draw [##1,/tikz/.cd,rounded corners=1pt,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
        plot coordinates {(0cm,0.8em) (2*\pgfplotbarwidth,0.6em)};
    },
},}         
\begin{axis}[hide y axis,axis x line=bottom,
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    %ylabel=Year,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar,bar width=2em,
    %symbolic x coords={2009,2010,2011,2012},
    ybar legend,
    nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta},
    every node near coord/.append style={
    anchor=mid west,
    rotate=70} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27143/121799
]
\addplot[rounded corners=8pt,fill=blue!60!black,
] 
    coordinates {(2009,412156) (2010,414870) (2011,408348) (2012,408184)};
\addplot [rounded corners=8pt,fill=red!60!black]  
    coordinates {(2009,395972) (2010,398449) (2011,393007) (2012,388950)};
\legend{Men,Women}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could we also remove the y axis and have the corresponding values at the top of each bar?

Comment: thank you very much! very good answer! (+1)